# Initializing pointer to string: garbled text?

Tags: c, string

I get garbled text and a wrong return value after initializing a pointer to a char array. I don't get it at all. I use Linux gcc as compiler.

Tried also with this online compiler, same results:
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

// Prototypes -------------------------------------------------------------{{{1

void get_extension(const char *file_name, char *extension);
bool test_extension(const char *file_name, const char *extension);

// Main function ----------------------------------------------------------{{{1

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", test_extension("name.txt", "txt"));
    return 0;
}

// Functions definitions --------------------------------------------------{{{1


void get_extension(const char *file_name, char *extension)
{
    int i;
    strcpy(extension, "");
    for (i=0; i < strlen(file_name) - 1; ++i)
        if ( file_name[i] == '.' ) break;
    if ( i == strlen(file_name) - 1 ) return;
    strcpy(extension, &file_name[i+1]);
}

bool test_extension(const char *file_name, const char *extension)
{
    char ext[] = "";
    get_extension(file_name, ext);

    printf("%s %s\n", ext, extension); // values before pointer init
    char *p = ext;
    printf("%s %s\n", ext, extension); // why did the string change??

    while ( *extension )
        if ( toupper(*p++) != toupper(*extension++) ) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

I expect the return value to be 1, and not getting garbled text in the second printf() call.

Comment: `char ext[] = "";` defines an array of size `1`. It has room for only a string terminator but no content. Trying to copy any other string to it, except the empty string, is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `char ext[] = "";`, `ext` is a `char[1]`. In `get_extension`, you attempt to write the whole extension into it, which obviously won't fit. Writing past the bounds of an array is Undefined Behavior, which means anything can happen.

Comment: Thanks. I was mislead by the fact that the first time the string was printed correctly, and for some wrong reason I thought that `strcpy` would resize the array on its own, starting from an empty string.